# MySQL setting in Innosetup

Tags: mysql, inno-setup

In Innosetup I can create a new user without any problem.
The only issue I have, is that I have to set the amount of Simultaneous connections to 200 and this is what I cannot get working.
Does somebody have an idea how to set this right?

Comment: This looks like [tag:mysql] question, rather then [tag:inno-setup] question. And it's questionable whether this is programming question at all.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `show variables like "max_connections";` to see the what max_connections is currently set to.

To change `max_connections` until server is restarted, you can run `set global max_connections = 200;` It will set max connections to `200`.

To permanently change max_connections you would have to edit your config file. And add `max_connections = 200` under the `[mysqld]` section.

Comment: Thank you for your reaction.
What I mean, is that I want the setting should be made when the Innosetup file is running. Not afterwards. I think that the should be a parameter in de setup but I don't know what.
The required user is added correctly including the right password. Only the maximum connections are not set automatically.

Comment: What have you tried and can you provide an example on how you set the variables now?

Comment: This is what's in Innosetup:

Filename: {pf}\MySQL\Bin\mysql.exe; StatusMsg: Configure MySQL; Components: Mysql; Flags: waituntilterminated runhidden; WorkingDir: {pf}\MySQL\Bin\; Parameters: "--user=root --execute=""GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO '[user]'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '[password]' WITH GRANT OPTION; SET max_connections FOR '[user]'@'%' = '200'""";